# Cannot download a .zip file in Google Drive API C#

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using Google Drive API to download file. Everything is fine with .doc, .pdf, .txt,...

But I cannot download .zip file.

Here is my code:

```
FilesResource.ListRequest listRequest = driveService.Files.List();
listRequest.Q = "'1QGXl3VbkzdygMJO4hocqpzmAeFjFS73S' in parents";
listRequest.PageSize = 10;
listRequest.Fields = "nextPageToken, files(id, name, size)";
IList<Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File> VersionFiles = listRequest.Execute().Files;
foreach (Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file in VersionFiles)
{
    var request = driveService.Files.Get(file.Id);
    var streamDownload = new System.IO.MemoryStream(
    request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += (IDownloadProgress progress) =>
    {
        switch (progress.Status)
        {
            case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
                    break;
                }
            case DownloadStatus.Completed:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");

                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("12345", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        streamDownload.WriteTo(fs);
                        fs.Flush();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            case DownloadStatus.Failed:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                    break;
                }
        }

    request.Download(streamDownload);
}
```

[image]
It always return failed and Exception: "The specified data could not be decrypted".

Please help. thanks.

Comment: Please don't post images. Instead, copy the exception and stacktrace.

Comment: Have you tried downloading another zip file? Create one and try it.